# How to add a custom Bibtex entry type?

Tags: bibtex

I would like to define a Bibtex entry type for legal documents with some specific fields like number of legislative directive etc. I added the fields to the ENTRY command and wrote a function to handle the formatting:

```
FUNCTION {legislation}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.documentnumber "documentnumber" output.check
  format.title.p "title" output.check
  blank.sep
  note "note" output.check
  fin.entry
}
```

Unfortunately, bibtex still processes it as a miscellaneous entry type (the default type).

How can I make it recognize the @legislation entry type?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.